# Which ayah of Quran states that if it wasn't for Allah we would all have followed Shaytaan except a few?

Tags: reference-request, ayah

A long time ago I was reading Quran translation and I came across an ayah which was translated roughly as below.

> If it wasn't for us shaytan would lead all people astray.

technically it mentions how shaytan influence is so strong if Allah helped people no one would've been guided can someone recall this ayah if so can you tell me where is it.

Comment: @crimson thanks that what i were looing for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The last part of Surah Nisa' Ayat 83 has a similar meaning to what you have quoted:

[image]

> And when there comes to them information about [public]
>   security or fear, they spread it around. But if they had referred it
>   back to the Messenger or to those of authority among them, then the
>   ones who [can] draw correct conclusions from it would have known about
>   it. **And if not for the favor of Allah upon you and His mercy, you
>   would have followed Satan, except for a few.**
>
> <sub>[Surah An-Nisa':83](http://corpus.quran.com/translation.jsp?chapter=4&verse=83)</sub>